# SQL Server Convert MMM-YYYY as real date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have dates in the form of Apr-2019, May-2019 etc., which is stored in the field name MonthYear.

But when I sort the data using order by MonthYear then it sorts the data in Alphabetical order (i.e.)

[image]

How would I convert the MonthYear as real date so that it shows the MonthYear in correct order.

Comment: `ORDER BY convert(date, '01-' + yourcolumn)`

Comment: Wow!!! Please post your solution as reply I will mark it as Answer :)

Comment: You shouldn't store such values in the first place. Store dates as dates, convert to `MMM-YYYY` when selecting from the table. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (MonthYear Varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
('Jan-2019'),('Feb-2019'),('Mar-2019'),('Apr-2019'),('May-2019'),
('Jun-2019'),('Jul-2019'),('Aug-2019'),('Sep-2019'),('Oct-2019'),
('Nov-2019'),('Dec-2019'),('Jan-2020')

SELECT
MonthYear
,CAST('1-'+MonthYear AS DATE) AS [Date]
FROM @TBL
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: This will fail in any language that's not English. Try adding `SET LANGUAGE French;` (or any other language in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and see what happens.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . The question has dates in English.  Although you do make a valid point, I hope you didn't downvote the answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the question was asked using the English Language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and JonWay - So what if the question has dates in English? The language the query will run with, unless set explicitly using `set language`, will be the default language of the login. Can any of you know for sure that this language is English and not, say, Italian, French or any other language? Adding `Set language English;` before the script would be the sensible thing to do. without it, this answer does deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your SQL server doesn't interpret your column as a date.
You may add the first day of the month to your column and convert it to date when you sort.

```
SELECT * FROM 
`your_db`.`your_table` 
ORDER BY 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `your_column`), '%d-%b-%Y')
```

Edit:
Zohar was right that the syntax above is correct for MySQL only.

Please use the following for SQL server:

```
ORDER BY 
CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('01-', your_column), 103)
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support `STR_TO_DATE`... You're thinking about MySql.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you're right I've edited my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have dates in the form of Apr-2019, May-2019 etc., which is stored in the field name MonthYear.

That's the source of your problem. You shouldn't store such values in your table.
Instead, store proper dates, and convert them to whatever string representation you want to in the presentation layer.

Be sure to store the dates in a column with a meaningful, descriptive name. Don't call it `Date` because it's not actually the date you care about, it's a combination of the month and a year. 
However, `MonthYear` might also not be the best choice for this column's name.

I would suggest `MonthStartDate` or something along these lines.
This name both describe what data the column stores, and also means that the date resolution you need to deal with is month and not day.

You can, if you want to, add a computed column to the table to store the MMM-YYYY value of the date. That would allow you to keep the presentation layer as it is now, however keep in mind it shouldn't be the database responsibility to provide ready-to-display data.

Here's a demo:

Create sample table:

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (
    MonthStartDate date,
    MonthYear AS REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(11), MonthStartDate, 113), 8), ' ', '-') 
);
```

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO @TBL (MonthStartDate) VALUES
('2019-01-01'), ('2019-02-01'), ('2019-03-01'),
('2019-04-01'), ('2019-05-01'), ('2019-06-01'),
('2019-07-01'), ('2019-08-01'), ('2019-09-01'),
('2019-10-01'), ('2019-11-01'), ('2019-12-01'),
('2020-01-01');
```

Verify that the MonthYear column returns desired results:

```
SELECT MonthStartDate, MonthYear
FROM @TBL
ORDER BY MonthStartDate
```

Results:

```
MonthStartDate  MonthYear
2019-01-01      Jan-2019
2019-02-01      Feb-2019
2019-03-01      Mar-2019
2019-04-01      Apr-2019
2019-05-01      May-2019
2019-06-01      Jun-2019
2019-07-01      Jul-2019
2019-08-01      Aug-2019
2019-09-01      Sep-2019
2019-10-01      Oct-2019
2019-11-01      Nov-2019
2019-12-01      Dec-2019
2020-01-01      Jan-2020
```